# ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-06512: at line 5 and ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at line 5

Tags: oracle, plsql

procedure created accurately but execution time getting error mentioned in title.

```
DECLARE
     var NUMBER;
     var1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
     sale_procedure(outletid => 809,itemcod => 128169,start_date => '2018-1-1',end_date => '2019-1-1'
     ,amount => var,quantity => var1);

     dbms_output.enable;
     dbms_output.put_line(var);
End;
/
```

Comment: With a specific Oracle error message like ORA-01843 it's always worthwhile [popping it into the SO search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-01843). There are several, if not dozens, of answered questions for all the common errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass `DATE` literal, i.e. just add the  word date before your dates, it should work, provided the arguments `start_date` and `end_date`  are defined as dates.

```
 sale_procedure(
      outletid  => 809,
      itemcod   => 128169
    ,start_date => DATE '2018-01-01'
     ,end_date  => DATE '2019-01-01'
     ,amount    => var,
     quantity   => var1
 );
```

Comment: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "CSDENT.SALE_PROCEDURE", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 5

Comment: @shabanaAfzal : That error is not because of the way it is called. Something's wrong in your procedure `SALE_PROCEDURE`  at line 3/ line 5 as it is clearly reported in the error.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SALE_PROCEDURE(OUTLETID  IN number,itemCod IN number,START_Date IN DATE, END_DATE IN DATE,AMOUNT OUT NUMBER,Quantity OUT NUMBER )IS BEGIN select Sum(Amount)Amount,sum(quantity)Quantity  INTO AMOUNT,Quantity from IDSTRANSACTION i join lup l on l.OUTLET_ID=i.outlet_id JOIN LUP_ZONES Z ON Z.ZONE_ID=L.ZONE_ID join product p on p.serial =itemCode join lup_master m on  m.sup_id = p.Supplier_ID where l.OUTLET_ID in (OUTLETID ) and  itemCode in (itemCod) and to_date(i.Entry_Date) between To_date('START_Date', 'MM,DD,YYYY') and To_date('END_DATE', 'MM,DD,YYYY');END;

Comment: @shabanaAfzal : Check your `where` clause. You only need `BETWEEN  start_date and end_date`.Please fix it. By the way,  I have answered your original question. If you found the answer useful, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
it so that it would also help others. Any new issue should be asked as a separate question and not dragged in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the dates passed as an input parameter (START_Date, END_DATE) need to be "Date" datatype or use the string format according to your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting.
The string can be directly used in place of dates if they are according to NLS setting.

Better to use to_date function or date ''.

example: to_date('01-01-2019','dd-mm-rrrr')

Comment: Please **edit your answer** to improve it rather than using the comment section. It should be possible to delete a comment without losing any information. In particular code is hard to read as a comment due to the poor layout and lack of formatting.

Comment: Also, the RR date mask element which Oracle introduced as s a kludge for the Y2K bug back in the late nineties. There should be no excuse for using it in 2019. Indeed, it's a red flag as it is likely to be masking data corruption.